# Kendo Charts for Angular: Kendo Chart data gets cut off at the top

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

For some reason the data in my kendo charts get cut off at the top. As you may see below.

[image]

I've attempted multiple fixes like looking for ways to implement padding. But failed. The best solution I've come up with was adding kendo-chart-pane and setting the input clip="false".
See example below

[image]

It was a great fix, until I realized it conflicts with zooming. Because we set clip=false, when a user zooms into a graph the date overlays the graph, because its not being clipped anymore. Just like below

[image]

Anyone have any ideas, where I can keep the clip without breaking the Zoom.

HTML

```
  <kendo-chart
    *ngIf="hasTrend; else noData"
    class="mt-2 chart"
    [seriesDefaults]="chartOptions.seriesDefaults"
    [series]="chartOptions.series"
    [categoryAxis]="chartOptions.categoryAxis"
    [valueAxis]="chartOptions.valueAxis"
    [pannable]="{ lock: 'y' }"
    [zoomable]="{ mousewheel: { lock: 'y' }, selection: { lock: 'y' } }"
  >
    <kendo-chart-tooltip [shared]="true">
      <kendo-chart-panes>
        <kendo-chart-pane [clip]="false">
          <ng-template kendoChartSharedTooltipTemplate let-category="category" let-points="points">
            <div class="tooltip">
              <strong>{{ getDateFormat(category) }}</strong>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let point of points">
                <div
                  *ngIf="point.series.name !== 'predictionBar' && (point.value !== null || point.value === 0) && point.value !== '--'"
                  class="d-flex align-item-center justify-content-between"
                >
                  <span
                    *ngIf="point.series.name"
                    [ngStyle]="{ color: point.series.color === 'transparent' ? '#000000' : point.series.color }"
                    [innerHtml]="point.series.name"
                  ></span>
                  <strong
                    class="pl-2"
                    [ngStyle]="{ color: point.series.color === 'transparent' ? '#000000' : point.series.color }"
                    [innerHtml]="point.value | format: format:measure"
                  ></strong>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-chart-pane>
      </kendo-chart-panes>
    </kendo-chart-tooltip>

    <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
  </kendo-chart>
  <ng-template #noData>
    <div class="no-data-container mt-3 mb-3">
      <h5>{{ 'no_trend_desc' | translate }}</h5>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Clipping occurs at the axis line boundary which limits our options. Increasing the axis maximum (e.g. to 105%) is the only option I can think of.

Comment: @TsvetomirTsonev Thank you! That was the only solution I could come up with as well.